# Creating a grouped boxplot with separately coloured dots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped boxplot (by the "majorCluster" and "treatment" variables) with overlaid dots which are coloured by a different variable (the "aid" variable). All the approaches I've tried have changed the colouring of the dots, but the positions fail to match with the boxplot. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Here is my code:

```
  ggplot(data = boxplot.data, aes(x=majorCluster, y=expa)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = fct_rev(factor(treatment))), width = 0.5, size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", trim = FALSE, dotsize = 0.5,position = position_dodge(0.8), aes(color = fct_rev(factor(treatment)), fill = fct_rev(factor(treatment)))) +
  theme_classic()
```

Here is the output (desired output = dots have different colours based on "aid" variable)
[image]

Here is the data (dput):

```
boxplot.data <- structure(list(aid = c("Anti-PD-L1 A", "Anti-PD-L1 A", "Anti-PD-L1 A", 
"Anti-PD-L1 A", "Anti-PD-L1 B", "Anti-PD-L1 B", "Anti-PD-L1 B", 
"Anti-PD-L1 B", "Anti-PD-L1 C", "Anti-PD-L1 C", "Anti-PD-L1 C", 
"Anti-PD-L1 C", "Anti-PD-L1 D", "Anti-PD-L1 D", "Anti-PD-L1 D", 
"Anti-PD-L1 D", "Untreated A", "Untreated A", "Untreated A", 
"Untreated A", "Untreated B", "Untreated B", "Untreated B", "Untreated B"
), majorCluster = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", 
"3", "4"), expa = c(0.00229641856789997, 0.00449718430290869, 
0.0079476155988667, 0.0323137314979365, 0.125655399176487, 0.0737804421330638, 
0.0552815368690545, 0.0467782242054685, 0.00143345514424931, 
0.0055910433498606, 0.00647918094834399, 0.0150090372519559, 
0.0167864512842503, 0.0243240630288888, 0.0404105646363485, 0.0267541240801361, 
0.00925515666671728, 0.0115509845370231, 0.0276374627000041, 
0.0438400723313962, 0.0403818878060491, 0.0481121640688924, 0.0545189407651033, 
0.0764620370634215), migr = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), tran = c(0.335015348105744, 
0.376269513326694, 0.449228611310031, 0.446682573678422, 0.842635301541922, 
0.765588148505148, 0.683233418019828, 0.610651263240787, 0.18994141256059, 
0.232057278886713, 0.281840445619523, 0.351757256110902, 0.472126089570835, 
0.599354493054942, 0.707113638164233, 0.810238120454871, 0.483691176581404, 
0.609864164601998, 0.685779002499795, 0.716753100388738, 0.743285518118052, 
0.708765108329113, 0.74453010103349, 0.912753289862157), treatment = c("Atezo", 
"Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", 
"Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", "Atezo", 
"Atezo", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
"None")), row.names = c("17", "21", "31", "41", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "111", "211", 
"311", "411", "51", "61", "71", "81"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `group` to your aes call in `geom_point` (which I use instead of `geom_dot`, because I guess this is what you want...)

Use a fillable shape for the use of fill, so you can use both color and fill aesthetic for different legends

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = boxplot.data, aes(x=majorCluster, y=expa)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = fct_rev(factor(treatment))), width = 0.5, size = 0.4, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.8), 
             aes(group = fct_rev(factor(treatment)), 
                 fill = aid), shape = 21) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>